# How to use multiple networks inside a Hardhat Script?

Tags: hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I have a piece of code that deploys a contract. I would like to deploy this contract to two networks (lets say Goerli and MainnetEthereum). Inside a loop in hardhat script I can change the network using the following code:

```
for (const currNetwork of networksToDeploy) {
   hre.changeNetwork(currNetwork);
   const DToken = await DToken.deploy(...constructorArgs)
}
```

The network doesn't change, it double deploys it in Goerli (the first network). The loop is changing correctly but the provider on `DToken.deploy` stays the same. Any ideas on how to change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to be able to deploy cross-chain using [xDeployer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xdeployer):

By adding the settings to the `hardhat.js` and then running `npx hardhat xdeploy`.

More info is available in their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate two Wallets.

https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/signer/#Wallet-constructor

To create a Wallet you need to provide a private key and a provider (if desired) to instantiate a wallet.

```
new ethers.Wallet( privateKey [ , provider ] )
```

Here is an example code to instantiate two wallets:

```
const walletGoerli = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, goerliProvider);
const walletMumbai = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, mumbaiProvider);
```